# How to Go to a parent timeline properly in Flash actionscript 2?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, parent, timeline

I am using a tutorial for a Flash aplication, with several galleries. The issue is, when I click on a thumbnail photo, I don't know how to go up to the corresponding timeline to show that photo.

My code is (scene 2 is the corresponding timeline):

```
on(release)
{
   gotoAndPlay("Scene 3", 1);
}
```

The button does not work, it does when I write _root (as the tutorial said originally) but it takes to the very root timeline and I don't need that.

```
on(release)
{
   _root.gotoAndStop(3);
}
```

How can I do?

Comment: I believe `_parent.gotoAndStop(3)` is what you are looking for.  Though it's been almost a decade since I've done anything AS2...

Comment: @LDMS You have a good memory:)

Answer (score 0):

The stage containing your MovieClip (thumbnail photo) is its `parent`. So you can write:

```
_parent.gotoAndStop(3);
```

Your MovieClip is contained by another MovieClip itself contained by the stage, you'll write:

```
_parent._parent.gotoAndStop(3);
```

It's a better practice to use the keyword `_parent` than to use `_root` here. Generally: forget `_root` that is a bad coding practice. If you use `loadMovie`, variables used with `_root` are `undefined` in the loaded Movie! Target directly with `_parent`. Moreover it will be more clear for you and for the people who read your code.

So if you want to go to a parent properly, use `_parent`.

For nested MovieClips, to know if you are accessing the correct timeline, you can use the `trace` function (the Main Timeline is _level0):

```
trace(_parent);
trace(_parent._parent);
trace(_parent._parent._parent);
```